Compose: How Can I Smoothly Partially Collapse a Panel?
I need to implement a panel that can be in three states: collapsed, fully expanded, and partially expanded. The panel is made up of three sections, and "partially expanded" keeps the middle section. This panel is not a bottom sheet; it appears above a button bar.
The state transitions of importance are:

From "collapsed", we always go to "fully expanded"
From "fully expanded", we always go to "partially expanded"
From "partially expanded", we go to "fully expanded" (in the real project, there are cases where we go to "collapsed", but I'm skipping that here to simplify things a bit)

The desired animation, at a high level, is a vertical slide (translation). So, when we go from "collapsed" to "fully expanded", we want the panel to slide up from the bottom. When we go from "fully expanded" to "partially expanded", we want the panel to slide (partially) to the bottom. When we go from "partially expanded" to "fully expanded", we want the panel to slide (partially) back up.
This GIF shows what I have now, which illustrates the general concept (also available as a non-looping MP4):

The part that isn't great about my implementation is what happens with the middle section of the panel. When we partially collapse, it remains in place while the bottom section animates away, snapping to the end state. When we partially expand, it snaps to the end state immediately, while the bottom section animates in.
A better animation would have these animate more in unison:

As the bottom section animates in or out, the middle section follows along. It would be as if the two sections were attached and I were animating the pair partway, just enough to fully hide (or fully show) the bottom section.
The top section would similarly be attached to the middle section. On a partial collapse, it would appear to "hide" behind the middle section, for example.

My current implementation uses a Column() and AnimatedVisibility(). This demo code is what gave me the screencast shown above:
package com.commonsware.threebodypanel

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibility
import androidx.compose.animation.core.MutableTransitionState
import androidx.compose.animation.slideInVertically
import androidx.compose.animation.slideOutVertically
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

private val PANEL_WIDTH = 520.dp
private val SECTION_HEIGHT = 100.dp
private val PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color(0x1e, 0x1e, 0x1e)
private val FULL_SECTION_COLOR = Color(0xff, 0xc2, 0x0a)
private val PERMANENT_SECTION_COLOR = Color(0x0c, 0x7b, 0xdc)

private val slideInUpwards = slideInVertically(
    initialOffsetY = {
        it / 2
    }
)
private val slideOutDownwards = slideOutVertically(
    targetOffsetY = {
        it / 2
    }
)

private enum class PanelState {
    Collapsed,
    Full,
    Partial
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        enableEdgeToEdge()

        WindowCompat
            .getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
            .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

        setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.Start)
            ) {
                val panelState = remember { mutableStateOf<PanelState>(PanelState.Collapsed) }
                val showPanel = remember { MutableTransitionState(false) }
                val showFullPanel = remember { MutableTransitionState(true) }

                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f))

                AnimatingPanel(showPanel, showFullPanel)

                ButtonBar {
                    when (panelState.value) {
                        PanelState.Collapsed -> {
                            panelState.value = PanelState.Full
                            showPanel.targetState = true
                            showFullPanel.targetState = true
                        }

                        PanelState.Full -> {
                            panelState.value = PanelState.Partial
                            showPanel.targetState = true
                            showFullPanel.targetState = false
                        }

                        PanelState.Partial -> {
                            panelState.value = PanelState.Full
                            showPanel.targetState = true
                            showFullPanel.targetState = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun AnimatingPanel(
        showPanel: MutableTransitionState<Boolean>,
        showFullPanel: MutableTransitionState<Boolean>,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visibleState = showPanel,
            enter = slideInUpwards,
            exit = slideOutDownwards
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = modifier,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                OptionalSection(showFullPanel)

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(PERMANENT_SECTION_COLOR)
                        .size(PANEL_WIDTH, SECTION_HEIGHT)
                )

                OptionalSection(showFullPanel)
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun OptionalSection(
        showFullPanel: MutableTransitionState<Boolean>,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visibleState = showFullPanel,
            enter = slideInUpwards,
            exit = slideOutDownwards
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = modifier
                    .background(FULL_SECTION_COLOR)
                    .size(PANEL_WIDTH, SECTION_HEIGHT)
            )
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ButtonBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onButtonClick: () -> Unit = {}) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .size(width = PANEL_WIDTH, height = 120.dp)
                .background(PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Surface(
                onClick = onButtonClick,
                modifier = Modifier.size(width = 115.dp, height = 49.dp),
                isEnabled = true,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                colorNormal = Color(0xd9, 0xd9, 0xd9, 0x4d),
                colorPressed = Color(0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x4d),
                colorDisabled = Color(0xd9, 0xd9, 0xd9, 0x1a)
            )
        }
    }
}

The full demo project can be found on GitHub. The showPanel animation is for moving between the collapsed and fully-expanded states, and the showFullPanel animation is for moving between the fully-expanded and partially-expanded states.
Any suggestions on how I can smooth out this animation?

The answer from Abdo21 definitely helped refine my thinking. I cut over to animateDpAsState() across the board. That gives me this effect, which is fine for my purposes:

The integration branch in the GitHub repo shows my end implementation:
package com.commonsware.threebodypanel

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateDpAsState
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.size
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.State
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.core.view.WindowCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

private val PANEL_WIDTH = 520.dp
private val SECTION_HEIGHT = 100.dp
private val PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color(0x1e, 0x1e, 0x1e)
private val FULL_SECTION_COLOR = Color(0xff, 0xc2, 0x0a)
private val PERMANENT_SECTION_COLOR = Color(0x0c, 0x7b, 0xdc)

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        enableEdgeToEdge()

        WindowCompat
            .getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
            .hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())

        setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxHeight()
                    .wrapContentWidth(Alignment.Start)
            ) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f))

                val panelState = remember { mutableStateOf(ThreeBodyPanelState.Collapsed) }

                ThreeBodyPanel(
                    panelState,
                    top = { modifier ->
                        Box(
                            modifier = modifier
                                .background(Color.Magenta)
                                .size(PANEL_WIDTH, SECTION_HEIGHT)
                        )
                    },
                    middle = {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .background(PERMANENT_SECTION_COLOR)
                                .size(PANEL_WIDTH, SECTION_HEIGHT)
                        )
                    },
                    bottom = {
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .background(FULL_SECTION_COLOR)
                                .size(PANEL_WIDTH, SECTION_HEIGHT)
                        )
                    },
                    topHeight = SECTION_HEIGHT,
                    middleHeight = SECTION_HEIGHT,
                    bottomHeight = SECTION_HEIGHT,
                    modifier = Modifier.background(Color.DarkGray)
                )

                ButtonBar {
                    when (panelState.value) {
                        ThreeBodyPanelState.Collapsed -> {
                            panelState.value = ThreeBodyPanelState.Full
                        }

                        ThreeBodyPanelState.Full -> {
                            panelState.value = ThreeBodyPanelState.Partial
                        }

                        ThreeBodyPanelState.Partial -> {
                            panelState.value = ThreeBodyPanelState.Full
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    enum class ThreeBodyPanelState {
        Collapsed,
        Full,
        Partial
    }

    @Composable
    fun ThreeBodyPanel(
        panelState: State<ThreeBodyPanelState>,
        top: @Composable (modifier: Modifier) -> Unit,
        middle: @Composable () -> Unit,
        bottom: @Composable () -> Unit,
        topHeight: Dp,
        middleHeight: Dp,
        bottomHeight: Dp,
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    ) {
        val animatedOverallHeight by animateDpAsState(
            targetValue = when (panelState.value) {
                ThreeBodyPanelState.Collapsed -> 0.dp
                ThreeBodyPanelState.Partial -> middleHeight
                ThreeBodyPanelState.Full -> topHeight + middleHeight + bottomHeight
            },
            animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500), // update this value as needed
            label = "animateDpAsState-overall"
        )

        Column(
            modifier = modifier.height(animatedOverallHeight),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom
        ) {
            val animatedTopHeight by animateDpAsState(
                targetValue = when (panelState.value) {
                    ThreeBodyPanelState.Full -> topHeight
                    else -> 0.dp
                },
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500), // update this value as needed
                label = "animateDpAsState-top"
            )

            top(Modifier.height(animatedTopHeight))

            val animatedRemainingHeight by animateDpAsState(
                targetValue = when (panelState.value) {
                    ThreeBodyPanelState.Full -> middleHeight + bottomHeight
                    else -> middleHeight
                },
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500), // update this value as needed
                label = "animateDpAsState-remaining"
            )

            Column(modifier = Modifier.height(animatedRemainingHeight)) {
                middle()
                bottom()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun ButtonBar(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, onButtonClick: () -> Unit = {}) {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .size(width = PANEL_WIDTH, height = 120.dp)
                .background(PANEL_BACKGROUND_COLOR),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {
            Surface(
                onClick = onButtonClick,
                modifier = Modifier.size(width = 115.dp, height = 49.dp),
                isEnabled = true,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                colorNormal = Color(0xd9, 0xd9, 0xd9, 0x4d),
                colorPressed = Color(0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x4d),
                colorDisabled = Color(0xd9, 0xd9, 0xd9, 0x1a)
            )
        }
    }
}

This is not the cleanest Compose code, but it illustrates the results nicely.

I’m not sure if this counts as an answer, but here’s another way to get smooth animations.
I used the AnimatedContent API for this example:
private val SECTION_HEIGHT = 100.dp

enum class PanelState {
    Hidden, Collapsed, Full, Partial,
}

fun transitTo(from: PanelState) : PanelState {
    return when (from) {
        PanelState.Hidden -> PanelState.Full
        PanelState.Collapsed -> PanelState.Full
        PanelState.Full -> PanelState.Partial
        PanelState.Partial -> PanelState.Collapsed
    }
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                var panelState by remember { mutableStateOf(PanelState.Hidden) }

                ThreeSectionPanel(
                    targetPanelState = panelState,
                    sectionContent1 = { SectionPanel(Color.Red) },
                    sectionContent2 = { SectionPanel(Color.Green) },
                    sectionContent3 = { SectionPanel(Color.Blue) },
                )

                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    onClick = {
                        panelState = transitTo(panelState)
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(text = "Expand or collapse")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun SectionPanel(backgroundColor: Color) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(SECTION_HEIGHT)
            .background(color = backgroundColor)
    )
}

@Composable
fun ThreeSectionPanel(
    targetPanelState: PanelState,
    sectionContent1: @Composable () -> Unit,
    sectionContent2: @Composable () -> Unit,
    sectionContent3: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    AnimatedContent(
        targetState = targetPanelState,
        transitionSpec = {
            ContentTransform(
                targetContentEnter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 50)),
                initialContentExit = fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 50))
            )
        },
        label = "AnimatedContent",
    ) { targetState ->
        Column(modifier = modifier) {
            // define in here the content you want to see for each state
            when (targetState) {
                PanelState.Hidden -> {
                    // nothing is visible
                }
                PanelState.Collapsed -> {
                    // only section 2 is visible
                    sectionContent2()
                }
                PanelState.Partial -> {
                    // section 1 and 2 are visible
                    sectionContent1()
                    sectionContent2()
                }
                PanelState.Full -> {
                    // all sections are visible
                    sectionContent1()
                    sectionContent2()
                    sectionContent3()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Demo:

Edit

I’ve made some changes to the ThreeSectionPanel to use the animateDpAsState.
Here’s the updated version:
@Composable
fun ThreeSectionPanel(
    targetPanelState: PanelState,
    sectionContent1: @Composable () -> Unit,
    sectionContent2: @Composable () -> Unit,
    sectionContent3: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val animatedHeight by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = when (targetPanelState) {
            PanelState.Hidden -> 0.dp
            PanelState.Collapsed -> SECTION_HEIGHT
            PanelState.Partial -> SECTION_HEIGHT * 2
            PanelState.Full -> SECTION_HEIGHT * 3
        },
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 500), // update this value as needed
        label = "animateDpAsState"
    )

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .height(animatedHeight)
    ) {
        sectionContent1()
        sectionContent2()
        sectionContent3()
    }
}

The rest of the code remains the same as before.
Here's a demo of the updated animation.

I hope this version meets your expectations!

Thanks! This shows the same basic effect that I am trying to avoid. For example, in your screencast, you see the blue box vanish, and only then do the green and red boxes slide down. That might be due to the use of fadeIn()/fadeOut() transitions, so I will experiment with this and report back.

I tried switching fadeIn()/fadeOut() transitions to the framework-supplied slideIntoContainer()/slideOutOfContainer(), and that didn't help. I tried using the slideInUpwards/slideOutDownwards that I already had defined, and it's not bad when we fully expand, but the partial collapse still shows the bottom box leaving before the middle box animates to its final position.

@CommonsWare I’ve updated my answer based on your feedback

It definitely gives me some ideas, thanks!

Thanks again! I posted an answer that uses animatedDpAsState() to get a nice effect.
